# How to restrict input textbox to accept only numbers for mobile(android,windows) and webpage in Angular4

Tags: angular

How to restrict input textbox to accept only numbers for mobile(android,windows) and webpage in Angular4? I am using cordova platform.Initially I used kepress event.it worked fine for webpages but for mobile textbox was accepting special characters.

Comment: `<input type="number">`? what else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for keyup as opposed to keypress:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', getInput, false);

   function getInput(e){
     /run your function here
}
```

This event needs to be subscribed to **outside** the `angular.module`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```html
<ion-input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
```